# How to get the referenced data from a Firebase Firestore reference?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a web app that gets data from Firestore v9.  My instance of Firestore has a field of data type "reference".

When I query and get the reference object, I get the below when I console.log the result.

[image: screenshot]

```js
const ref = collection(firestoreDb, "users", "a_user", "subscriptions")
const firebaseResponse = await getDocs(ref)

firebaseResponse.forEach(doc => {
    console.log(doc.data())
})
```

The output doesn't have the string which I could then use to place into another `collection` or `doc` function.

The field I'm using refers to this object:

[image: screenshot]

I expect the output to include price and product_name.

I found some similar questions but there not exactly what I was looking for:

- [How to query Firebase Firestore Reference data type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46751459)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/58300047
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/54310245

Comment: What is your expected output, and can you also provide us screenshot of your Firestore collection data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a `DocumentReference` field in your data, that is precisely the type that you'll get back when reading that data from Firestore. You'll need to call `get()` on that `DocumentReference` to get the data for the referenced document.

Comment: Thanks, this worked!  I was trying to parse some field where I could have just used the whole object as the input.

Comment: Frank van Puffelen, can't we get the data in just one call, for example getDoc(fetch_referenced_data=True)?

Comment: Firestore document reads are shallow. There is no way in the API to request data from the referenced document. To load data from the referenced document will require an extra call.